# error al instalar modulo playsound phyton 3.1

Tags: python-3.x

Buen dia

Estimados solicito su asistencia, instale Python version 3.1 para correr la instalación de autogpt en mi pc y de a poco me empezó a pedir módulos, los estuve instalando sin complicaciones con el comando `pip` hasta que llegue a instalar el módulo **playsound**, arrojándome el siguiente error

```py
PS C:\Users\Franc\OneDrive\Desktop\auto\Auto-GPT> pip3 install playsound
Collecting playsound
  Using cached playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
```

Si alguien me pudiera asistir en cómo solucionar este error por favor

Comment: ¿Es Python 3.1 (versión muy antigua y obsoleta) o 3.11 (la actual)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error that you have and this video help me so I think this can help you
note:(if one of this steps doesn't work continue and later return to that step)
https://youtu.be/SpLidAgQuHQ
(Sorry I am Spanish)

Comment: Buenas, Matemario23, bienvenido al sitio. Si hablas español has venido al lugar adecuado. Deberías traducir tu respuesta al español, que es el idioma oficial aquí. Además, las respuestas que contienen solo un link no son muy apreciadas aquí. Deberías extraer de ese video exactamente cómo se resuelve el problema que planteaba Francisco, qué pasos debe seguir, y describirlos aquí ... Internet cambia muchisimo y ese link puede pasar a estar muerto en cualquier momento.